# Stripe monthly subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

so at the moment ive coded a script where i can add items to a invoice and get the user to pay them i would like to change my script into a subscription

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

$lineItems = [
    [
        'price_data' => [
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'product_data' => [
                'name' => 'ice',
            ],
            'unit_amount' => 9.99 * 100,    //  convert to cents
            'tax_behavior' => 'exclusive'
        ],
        'quantity' => 1
       
    ],
    [
        'price_data' => [
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'product_data' => [
                'name' => 'ice2',
            ],
            'unit_amount' => 11.99 * 100,   //  convert to cents
            'tax_behavior' => 'exclusive'
        ],
        'quantity' => 2
        
    ],
    [
        'price_data' => [
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'product_data' => [
                'name' => 'Tip (not taxed)',
            ],
            'unit_amount' => 5 * 100,       //  convert to cents
        ],
        'quantity' => 1,
    ]
];



// Create Stripe checkout session
$checkoutSession = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
    'line_items' => $lineItems,
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => 'https://hey.com/paypal/checkout-success.php?provider_session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    'cancel_url' => 'https://hey.com/paypal/cart.php?provider_session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}'
]);

// Retrieve provider_session_id. Store in database.
//$checkoutSession->id;

// Send user to Stripe
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: " . $checkoutSession->url);
exit;
```

i know that i would need to change the mode to subscription but have no clue on how to add a subscription  item into the lineItems ? I need to be able to edit the price of the subscription. I also read that i have to edit the price in stripe dashboard where my site sells different products that the user sets the price?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has a full guide on how to create a Subscription through a Checkout Session in their docs here (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=checkout).

The biggest things you'll need to change are:

- Switching from `mode: payment` -> `mode: subscription`
- Adding at least one `line_item` that has a recurring price, which you can specify by setting the `line_items[].price_data.recurring` hash (see https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-recurring)

Comment: the second url seems to only show how to make a "payment" and the issue is im letting the user who owns the item set the price but from what i read i have to set the price in the dashboard